# Jenkins Pipeline script editor is not displayed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

I have created a job for Jenkins pipeline. However, I am unable to see the script editor box. Attached is teh image. Pls suggest how I can get the script editor. I am using Jenkins 2.19.4[image]

Comment: After the selection click on the Pipeline Tab, it will refresh the view showing you what you need ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the same version and it works fine for me.

a new version of 2.31 was released.
try to upgrade it and check again.

check the jenkins log for any errors

have you tried using it from SCM?

Comment: I think the problem is when I am installing Jenkins as a service. I re-set it up and did not have it as a Windows service. I was able to get it after doing this