# Unable to Find Script Field in Jenkins Pipeline Configuration

Tags: jenkins

I'm setting up a Jenkins pipeline, but I can't seem to find the field for adding a script. Any ideas why this might be happening?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a glitch/bug. Try looking into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377225/jenkins-pipeline-script-editor-is-not-displayed) and checking if the solution works for you.

Comment: your suggestion did not work, so I'm just copying a working pipeline that still contains the script part and it works